# Feature: Subscribing to Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, bookmarks

It happens to me very often that I see an interesting question that I'd like to know the answer to. I'll favorite it but then never get notified if there is a change. It would be very nice to have a "subscribe to question" feature, which sends me a notification if there is a new answer (or optionally an edit to an existing answer) to the question.

I don't know to what extent this is even within the realm of possibility for physics SE, as it's part of the larger SE framework, but I thought the idea might also be useful for other users, and didn't see this mentioned on meta.

Comment: This [has already been requested on mother meta for eight years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45360/263383).

Comment: Also of note you can subscribe to RSS feeds on a question by question basis. See the "question feed" link at the bottom of the side-bar on questions.

Comment: @dmckee That would probably do well as an answer

Comment: @David, Well, my feeling is that the many supporters of the question ACuriousMind linked and most people who come to meta to ask about this aren't envisioning RSS feeds (which seem to be slowly going extinct), but instead something on-site. But OK.

Comment: @dmckee Yeah, I agree it's probably not what people had in mind, but my thought is that the RSS feed still is a way of subscribing to activity on a question. I.e. just because an answer isn't the one the OP wants, it can still be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already one question-subscription service: each question has a RSS feed associated with it (for this question the URL is `https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/10943`).

The link appears at the bottom of the right-hand side-bar, and for this question with my current OS and my browser combination it looks like this:

[image]

Alas this is support for getting notification in your RSS reader, and not an on-site feature which seems to be what most people are expecting.

There are similar feeds for **user** (find the link on their profile) and **tags** (find the tag search page) you would like to follow.

Comment: Thanks, between this and ACuriousMind's link to the suggestion on meta.SE (which I of course upvoted) I'm up-to-date on the progress / partial existence of this feature.

Comment: -1, for the lack of hand-drawn circles.